# Function to print to console audio currentTime at certain increments

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to add a function that is checking the currentTime of the `audio` tag. If the currentTime is say, 5 seconds. I'd like to print to console some test value.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Chapter 1</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <style>body        { padding-top:80px; }</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1><span class="fa fa-play"></span> Chapter 1</h1>
            <br>
            <audio id="track" controls onplay="playStart()" ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = this.currentTime + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">
               <source src="joey_matt.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
               Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </audio>
            <span id="tracktime">0 / 0</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         function playStart() {
             console.log("The video has started to play");
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you seem to already have it: ontimeupdate is your friend.

Comment: I tried to write an in-line if stmt but it never printed. It seemed to skip right over it. I’ll try again.

Comment: If you are checking for strict equality, then yes it won't fire, except huge luck.  You need to determine a fork in between you consider it as being close enough to the value you are waiting for, or to round the value returned by `currentTime`.

Comment: @Kaiido that makes sense. I didn’t know it wasn’t continuous.